# Error: 'shape' argument of 'c_f_pointer' intrinsic at (1) must be of rank 1 fortran C mixed programing

Tags: c, fortran

I'm very new to the whole mixed fortran C programming. trying to compile the examples mentioned in [this page](http://www.pgroup.com/userforum/viewtopic.php?t=1764&highlight=fortran%20bind) but I get some error which I do not understand.
the C part compiles properly so I just put the fortran code here:

```
MODULE type_mod

  USE iso_c_binding

  TYPE, bind(c) :: type2_t
  INTEGER(c_int) :: idx, size
END TYPE type2_t

TYPE, bind(c) :: type3_t
INTEGER(c_int) :: idx, size
END TYPE type3_t

TYPE, bind(c) :: type1_t
TYPE(type2_t) :: params
TYPE(c_ptr) :: status
INTEGER(c_int) :: idx
END TYPE type1_t

END MODULE type_mod

PROGRAM test_f_to_c

  USE iso_c_binding
  USE type_mod

  INTERFACE
     SUBROUTINE init_data(A,N) bind(c)
   USE iso_c_binding
   USE type_mod
   TYPE(type1_t) :: A
   INTEGER(c_int), value :: N
     END SUBROUTINE init_data
  END INTERFACE

  INTEGER, value :: N
  PARAMETER(N=10)
  TYPE(type1_t) :: A
  INTEGER :: i
  TYPE(type3_t), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: status

  CALL init_data(A,N)

  PRINT *, A%idx, A%params%idx, A%params%size
  CALL c_f_pointer(A%status,status,[N])
  DO i=1,N
     PRINT *, i, status(i)%idx, status(i)%size
  ENDDO

END PROGRAM test_f_to_c
```

and I compile it with

```
gfortran -c foo.f90
```

and the error I get:

```
test13F.f90:35:33:
 CALL c_f_pointer(A%status,status,N)
                                 1
Error: 'shape' argument of 'c_f_pointer' intrinsic at (1) must be of rank 1
```

I would appreciate if you could help me understand why I'm getting this error, how can I solve it, and if there are other examples please give a link.

P.S. sorry if the indentations of the code are messy. I wish stackoverflow had a proper tool for copy and pasting code which wouldn't mess up with indentations like this!

edit1: based on the comments I fixed the code and it should work now.

Comment: The message means that the argument matching `shape` must be an array rather than a scalar.  In your case, simply  `call c_f_pointer(A%status,status,[N])`

Comment: thanks a lot. it was so easy, why the compiler message is so confusing? what does that rank means?

Comment: o! so my bad. I'm not a fortran programer. just started learning. you helped a lot. tnx.